# How to convert to DateTime but have default value if input is blank?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, tryparse

What `.NET` function will convert to a `DateTime` but have a default value if input is blank?

eg.

```
DateTime dtTest = Convert.ToDateTime(getDateString());
```

If `getDateString()` returns an empty string `Convert.ToDateTime` throws an exception.

How can I instead have a default value of `"9:00AM"` used instead of the empty string?  Is this something where `TryParse` could be used?

Comment: Well indeed you can use `TryParse`, but i am not sure if `9:00AM` is really a `DateTime` or you meant like Current Date with that time.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) and if the parsing fails you can assign `DateTime.MinValue.AddHours(9)` to get `(9:00AM)` time with Minimum Date.

```
string str = "";
DateTime temp;
DateTime dt = DateTime.TryParse(str, out temp) ? temp : DateTime.MinValue.AddHours(9);
```

For the above code your `dt` object will hold `{01/01/0001 9:00:00 AM}`

Comment: (with newer versions?) `temp` is not needed.
`DateTime dt = DateTime.TryParse(str, out dt) ? dt : DateTime.MinValue;`

Answer (score 5):

I have used something called a ternary statement. You can view an example here: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ty67wk28%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

```
    string myDate = getDateString();
    DateTime dtTest = Convert.ToDateTime(String.IsNullOrEmpty(myDate) ? "my default value" : myDate);
```

The ternary statement is below:

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(myDate) ? "my default value" : myDate
```

And it can be read as follows:

> If the string is null or empty, then use "my default value", otherwise use myDate.

Answer (score 2):

You should separate this into two parts:

- Work out what string you want to parse
- Work out what you want the result to be if that string *can't* be parsed

For example:

```
string text = GetDateString(); // Name converted to follow .NET conventions
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
{
    text = "9:00AM"; // Or whatever
}

DateTime parsed;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(text, out parsed))
{
    parsed = // some default here
}
```

Also consider using `TryParseExact` instead of `TryParse`, if you know what format you're expecting - and which culture you want to parse it as.

An alternative to having a default *string* value is to just have a default `DateTime` value and not bothering to parse if the text is null:

```
string text = GetDateString(); // Name converted to follow .NET conventions
DateTime parsed;

// This will only try to parse if text is non-null and non-empty
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) || !DateTime.TryParse(text, out parsed))
{
    parsed = // some default here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Write a wrapper function which returns default value when validation fails as follows,

```
public DateTime Validate(string dateString)
{
        DateTime dt;
        if(DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dt))
            return dt;
        else
            return DateTime.Now; //default value


}
```

Comment: You can't set DateTime dt=null

Answer (score 0):

```
  DateTime ToDateTime(string sourceValue){
    DateTime result;
    if(DateTime.TryParse(sourceValue, out result)
    return result
    else{
    result=new DateTime(2013,1,1) //default value, whatever you want
return result
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this:

```
DateTime MyDate;
DateTime ParsedDate;

if (DateTime.TryParse(txtNotificationDate.Text.Trim(), out ParsedDate))
{
    MyDate= ParsedDate;
}
else
{
    MyDate = DateTime.Now;
}
```